# Svchost.exe using upload

Tags: windows-10, spyware, svchost

I've noticed that This program `Svchost.exe` (a windows program) uses a little bit of upload whenever I do something. Its not slowing my PC down or anything, I'm just monitoring it and it uploads a little bit of data whenever I do any of the following: Open any program, Close any Program, Move from one Textbox to another, Edit a photo and save it, save a word document, save a text document, right click, kill a process with Taskkill, or say the words "Is Microsoft watching me". (Just kidding on that last one). Im probably just being paranoid but anyone know what it is doing? I've scanned it with MalwareBytes to find nothing bad, and I think it is Microsoft's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scvhost is, literally, the Host Process For Services. By itself it is nothing, but, depending on your Windows version, each instance of svchost.exe will be hosting one or more services, and these are not limited to Microsoft published services. Any software or driver that creates a service also uses svchost.exe as the host.

The Task manager makes it quite easy to see which service(s) each svchost executable is running, and other tools such as Process Explorer (by Microsoft from Sysinternals) make it even easier.

In order to figure out WHICH service is doing this uploading you will have to use either of these tools to find the specific service.

Also, yes, Microsoft and many other common pieces of software are collecting information based on your usage. That's common knowledge.